# How can I export multiple animations into one .x file?

Tags: animation, export

When I export my models and animations I use a .x (Direct X) format. I can see how this format [could accommodate multiple animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, I can't get Blender to export anything other than the **active action**. I have my animations in different actions, as described in [this question/answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183/how-can-i-manage-multiple-animations-in-one-blend-file).

How can I export multiple animations into one .x file? I'm using the built in exporter for .x files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender has a DirectX exporter. Go to *Addons* in User Preferences and look under *Import/Export*.

[image]

Check *Export Animations*, this should export all the animations in your file. I would recommend playing with the other animation options as well. You can read up on each setting on its [wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/DirectX_Exporter).

[image]

*Test 1:* I enabled it and made a simple scene with two animations. I exported the file to `.x` and opened it in a text editor and I saw the animations in there clearly labeled and with the transform locations I had used.

*Test 2:* I also downloaded a `.x` viewer called [3dmodelviewer](http://www.kumkie.com/3dmodelviewer/), exported a file from Blender with over 6 animations and it loaded and played them all so the exporter works with multiple animations.

***NB:*** In my tests, I parented primitives to several different bones. I also noticed that I had to be in `pose mode` when I was animating the objects, if not it doesn't work, not sure why.

Comment: I guess I just had to update Blender. This is a newer version of the exporter that has more options, including the one I needed. Thanks for the work you put into testing your solution and taking the time to make the answer look nice.