# Can multiple animations be saved in a .blend file?

Tags: animation, blend-files

With the current version, I created a simple mesh with bones, and by using the Dope Sheet I created two actions. I made animations for each action. Then I exported to FBX to check in Unity3d. So I saw that Blender is good enough for my needs. Then I saved this stuff into a .blend file.

Some time later I loaded this file and saw there was only one animation. I re-created another and saved, exited Blender, and re-loaded the file. The only animation was loaded with what I exited the program.

**My question is**: *what is the **proper** way to create multiple animations* with Blender, such that *they can be re-loaded*. *I would like to have a separate timeline for each animation*.

(Script is good too, because I want this for an importer; wanted to test it before coding.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue is that Blender is not saving the animation datablocks because there aren't any objects using them. You can protect the datablocks by [adding a fake user](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2448/290) like so:

1. Go to the NLA editor
2. Select the Action
3. Open your properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>)
4. In the top panel (*Animation Data*) select the action you want to protect from the dropdown.
5. Click the *F* next to the name to give the action a fake user:

   [image: Animation Data panel]

Alternatively this can be done in the header of the *Dope Sheet* editor while in [*Action Editor* mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet#Dope_Sheet_Modes).

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you. Note here to other beginners like me, that the animations with "fake user" can still be used by the mesh.

Comment: I tried adding using the F button on each of my actions, but in Unity the only animation is the one I was working on when I saved the .blend file.  Also the animation is called Default Take.  This is so frustrating...