# Some parts of my project aren't saved in the .blend file

Tags: customization

I created a model and added some Actions in the DopeSheet editor (more or less 5).

I exported the model to my game engine, saved the .blend file (Ctrl-S) and closed it.

Then I opened it again, and all the actions were gone, it just had the one I was using last.

The same happens with some preferences (for example, I disabled mip-maps on User Preferences -> System, and I have to re-enable it every time I open the .blend file again.

Does somebody knows how to restore the Actions and save everything? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/can-multiple-animations-be-saved-in-a-blend-file, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/save-custom-layout-in-blender-2-67b/1522#1522

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender does not save unused datablocks you need to add a fake user to store datablocks that are not in use. See [DataSystem Sections Users and Fake User](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Data_System)

The setting of mip-maps is not stored in a .blend file you would need to save the user-preferences in the same dialog (button in the lower left corner).

Related:

[What does "users" means in term of datablocks?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-does-users-means-in-term-of-datablocks)