# Animation Actions are missing!

Tags: animation, actions

I saved and closed my project, but after opening again there are only 52 actions in my Action Editor instead of the 72 I made? How is this possible?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/some-parts-of-my-project-arent-saved-in-the-blend-file

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Unfortunately this is exact what happend. Have to do every animation again (aaargh) On the plus side; just learned something new. For everybody who's new to Blender (like me) this is a good explanation about why an action needs a 'fake user': https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p27yGNIDrIU

Comment: PS This is such a weird 'work around' in even a 2.8 version. Why isn't this automated?

Comment: I believe it's an 'in-progress' task to get rid of fake users altogether: https://developer.blender.org/T61209

Comment: Great! Good to read it's a common pain for (new users), but also good to know the reason why it was implemented in the first place. Hope they will fix it: Constantly checking a box called 'fake user' doesn't feel very trustworthy if you ask me. Even though the icon is a shield. 

Thanks for helping me out on this subject btw., much appreciated.