# Error when trying to export mesh/armature FBX file to Unity

Tags: export, import, unity

I have been trying to move a blend file with three animations from Blender to Unity.

First I tried exporting the file from Blender to Unity and I got the below error.[image]

Then I tried importing from Blender into Unity and the mesh and armature would import fine, but only the animation that was currently selected in Blender would play. So I selected the second animation in blender, imported from Unity and then did the same for the third and final animation. So now I have three versions of the same mesh in Unity, each with a different animation in my assets folder.

Can someone please tell me how to get all the Blender animations in? I already asked on the Unity forums and no one seemed to know

Link to Unity Post: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1266045/how-to-import-all-animations-from-a-blend-file-int.html#comment-1267899

Blend File: [image]

Comment: The screenshot you show is when you are trying to import an FBX into Blender? It looks like the same type of error that occurs when you try to import an FBX into Blender if the FBX cannot be understood by Blender due to the fact the FBX was generated via Maya. What is the link to the forum on Unity3d? You shouldn't need to manually export an FBX for usage in Unity. Unity/Blender does this automatically for you when you import the .blend file into the project folder.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the link to the post. I haven't used Maya for anything here. Everything was made in Blender. The first comment tells me to export as FBX, which you said I shouldn't have to do and also gave me the error. The second comment told me to split one animation up in Unity, but I would prefer to just use them already separated.

Comment: Every blender file with animations I have seen have always used the approach of splitting the animations up in Unity, and not having multiple animations inside the blender file. But I tried the approach of importing multiple animations from the blend file and it seemed to work following this guide: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183/how-can-i-manage-multiple-animations-in-one-blend-file. I did not need to manually create the .FBX file. Also other people have had the same error message as you: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?390529-Blender-FBX-Exporter-Armature-Issue

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in the answer, but it seems to me that it is explaining how to create separate animations, which I already know how to do. i.e. Create animation, hit F to create fake user so it is permanently saved, open the animation in NLA editor and I think there is a snowflake thing you gotta press. It doesn't really seem to explain the process of exporting other than one comment that mentions removing the '.x', but there are no .x file formats. I've also attached my blend file now.

Comment: I downloaded your file and see what you mean. When imported into Unity, the only animation clip is "Default Take". When I open up your file I see an actions called TurnRight and TurnRight.001. I re-named TurnRight.001 to something else. After doing this, the model imports fine into Unity with the separate animation clips. So maybe it's a problem that TurnRight and TurnRight.001 are too similar of a name? Try re-naming it. The last link I posted contains some hint that the names were causing other people problems.

Comment: Dude you are awesome. That was the problem. Thank you so much.